# How to compare 3 columns of data?

Tags: python

My dataFrame be like:

```
  Original                  New

 A    B   C   |      D     E     F    G
50   30   50  |    None   None  50   None
10   10   10  |      10    10   10    10
30   20   20  |     None  None None   20
20   20   20  |      20    20   20    20
70   50   70  |     None  None  70   None
```

How to compare column A, B and C and create new column where D is where A==B==C, column E is where A==B, column F is where A ==C and column G is where B ==C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for compare multiple columns by one with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per rows:

```
d = df[['A','B','C']].eq(df['A'], axis=0).all(axis=1)
e =  df['A'] == df['B']
f =  df['A'] == df['C']
g =  df['B'] == df['C']
```

For new columns use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['D'] = np.where(d, df['A'], None)
df['E'] = np.where(e, df['A'], None)
df['F'] = np.where(f, df['A'], None)
df['G'] = np.where(g, df['B'], None)

print (df)
    A   B   C     D     E     F     G
0  50  30  50  None  None    50  None
1  10  10  10    10    10    10    10
2  30  20  20  None  None  None    20
3  20  20  20    20    20    20    20
4  70  50  70  None  None    70  None
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].where(d)
df['E'] = df['A'].where(e)
df['F'] = df['A'].where(f)
df['G'] = df['B'].where(g)

print (df)
    A   B   C     D     E     F     G
0  50  30  50   NaN   NaN  50.0   NaN
1  10  10  10  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
2  30  20  20   NaN   NaN   NaN  20.0
3  20  20  20  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
4  70  50  70   NaN   NaN  70.0   NaN
```